# symtab entries in a  .o file of  elf format

Tags: gcc, symbols, elf, object-files

i am learning about linking..
i wrote the following code in c and made .o using gcc

```
int f()
{
static int x=0;
return x;
}

extern int z;

int g()
{
static int x=10;
return x;
}

static int y;
static int y=9;

int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

then i made this into .o by:
    gcc begin.c -o begin.o

now when i checked the symtab using readelf there was no record of z....why?
also how does gcc allow two 'y'?
and in .data section how are the two 'x' differentiated?

Comment: Not sure how I missed this earlier, but your `gcc` command is producing an executable, not just an object file, named `begin.o`. Are you actually running it with `-c`?

Comment: it produces an executable object file which just needs to be loaded by the loader

Answer (score 0):

I'm an a rank non-expert, but I can hazard a couple guesses:

1. Since you only declare `z` but never actually use it, there is no need to maintain a reference to it.
2. Try adding `-Wall`, which will tell you (at least) that `y` is declared but unused. The first `y` is actually just a declaration, which you can repeat indefinitely as long as you do not declare a conflicting type.
3. In my compile, they end up being named `x.1281` and `x.1287`, so I guess it's something like the name-mangling that happens with C++. The 1281 and 1287 I would guess are the offsets of some relevance, although I am not able to see anything obvious.

Comment: @wil...i found the answer to the y part...actually initialised variables are strong and uninitialised are weak...and if there is a strong and a weak symbol with same name...strong is taken as the definition...i cant figure out 1st and 3rd questions